# How to hide all elements (tables) if their width is identical to some (200) pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Say I came across a page with 100 tables: 50 tables are of 100 width and 50 tables are of 200 width.

The tables of 200 width are irrelevant to me and I want to hide them with an `if ()` statement.

The problem his, they don't have a selector and I need to select time by their Width. Is this possible?

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
document.querySelectorAll('table').forEach( (e)=> {
  if (table.width === 300) {
    e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
});
```

**Edit:** I most desire a vanilla solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the offsetWidth property of the table elements, also make sure the dom is ready before trying to acces it :

```
function removeTables() { 
     document.querySelectorAll('table').forEach( (e)=> {
      if (e.offsetWidth >= 200) {
        e.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
 removeTables()
};
```

Comment: Hmm, this returns undefined even though the page clearly contains tables (a table, with tbody, td's, etc).

Comment: that is wierd, what does the console say when you log e?

Comment: are the tables in an iframe?

Comment: console.log(e); brings `ReferenceError: e is not defined`. Indeed it seems some tables in the webpage are part of a `frameset` with frame tags. I did see any relevant `iframe` tag though (there are a few which are clearly unrelated to the table I'm targeting).

Comment: try this  let tables = document.querySelectorAll('table'); console.log(tables) if this is undefined than my guess that the tables are not attached to the docuemnt object

Comment: Hmm, indeed, this is undefined. So you say the tables come from some pseudo-DOM (like, React's virtual DOM I would guess?)... Is there anything to do in such a case?

Comment: could be attached to a frame, or something like that

Comment: might have to recurse through the dom to get where you need

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896440/walk-up-dom-through-multiple-iframes-in-vanilla-js

Comment: is the page loaded when your running your code ?. like is wraped in a window.onload function. RaJesh answer addresed the dom being loaded

Comment: The page is indeed fully loaded when I run the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153288/discussion-between-timcodes-and-sangoko).

Comment: Hi, I replied there (added a link to it to bookmark toolbar to follow the discussion comfortably).

Answer (score 0):

Try below script. Here i used jquery `each()` function to iterate through all tables in the page. Hope it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').each(function(){
    if($(this).width()==125){
        $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Check this [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/wjL0fp5d/) for reference.

Comment: Can you please translate it to vanilla? I don't know jQuery. I will update the question I am looking for a vanilla solution. BTW I understand domContentLoaded is different than `$(document).ready` so It's a question what could replace it.

Comment: @sangoko sry dude, i have no idea about vanilla!!